# Retrieving data from vector from a fresh instance returns 0

Tags: c++, vector

I am creating an instance after updating records to the vector `vecData` inside `counter.cpp` when I am trying to retrieve this data I am getting the value as `0`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "counter.hpp"
#define MAX_PORTS 3

int main()
{
  Counter *counter = new Counter(3);
  counter->age = 1;
  counter->id = 12;
  counter->pincode = 123;

  std::vector<Counter> counterData(MAX_PORTS);

  counter->storeCounterData(counter,1);
  counter->storeCounterData(counter,2);
  counter->storeCounterData(counter,3);

  counter->getCounterData(counterData);

  // getCounterData here is not able to retrieve value updated in above vector `vecData`

  Counter *count = new Counter(3);
  count->getCounterData(counterData);
  return 0;
}
```

counter.cpp

```
#include "counter.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

Counter::Counter()
{  
}

Counter::Counter(int vecSize):vecData(vecSize)
{    
}

void Counter::storeCounterData(Counter *counter,int user)
{
  vecData[user].age = counter->age;
  vecData[user].id = counter->id;
  vecData[user].pincode = counter->pincode;

  std::cout<<"vector size inside storeCounterData = "<<vecData.size()<<std::endl;
}

void Counter::getCounterData(std::vector<Counter> &counter)
{
  counter = vecData;
  std::cout<<"vector size inside getCounterData = "<<vecData.size()<<std::endl;
  std::vector<Counter>::iterator it;

  for( it = vecData.begin(); it != vecData.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<vecData[1].age<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<vecData[1].id<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<vecData[1].pincode<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

counter.hpp

```
#include <vector>
class Counter
{
private:
std::vector<Counter> vecData; // vectors

public:
Counter();
Counter(int vecSize);
int age, id, pincode;
void storeCounterData(Counter *counter,int user);
void getCounterData(std::vector<Counter> &counter);

};
```

Output

> ./a.out vector size inside storeCounterData = 3
>
> vector size inside storeCounterData = 3
>
> vector size inside storeCounterData = 3
>
> vector size inside getCounterData = 3
>
> 1 12 123
>
> 1 12 123
>
> 1 12 123
>
> vector size inside getCounterData = 3
>
> 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0

Comment: Why, in `getCounterData`, do you loop through the `vector`, if you only want to print a specific element of a `vector`?

Comment: Can you please make your [mcve] a bit more minimal? I have a hard time to even find the vector

Comment: You never use `counter` in `getCounterData`. It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @NathanOliver vecData is a vector of objects of class  Counter and I intend to use the counter If I am able to atleast print the values of that vector

Comment: Why does `Counter` have a member `std::vector<Counter>`? You might want to split it into two classes. `Counter` with the `int` members, and `Counters` with the `std::vector<Counter>` member. You seem confused as to which objects you are using for which purposes

Comment: You're creating a new instance of Counter and somehow expect to be able to get out of it the same values that you put into a completely different instance? I don't know what could possibly make you think that it could work like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is C++, don't use macros for constants:

```
#define MAX_PORTS 3
```

Use a `const` variable instead:

```
const int max_ports = 3;
```

Why are you creating this variable on the heap?

```
  Counter *counter = new Counter(3);
  counter->age = 1;
  counter->id = 12;
  counter->pincode = 123;
```

C++ is not Java or C#, don't do that. You are failing to `delete` those variables, so you leak memory. Don't do that. This is the correct way:

```
  Counter counter(3);
  counter.age = 1;
  counter.id = 12;
  counter.pincode = 123;
```

Then either change `setCounterData` to take a reference, or pass in the address of the object:

```
  counter->storeCounterData(&counter,1);
```

You are indexing into the vector with the values `1`, `2` and `3`, but the vector only has three elements, so the correct indices are `0`, `1`, and `2`. Doing `vecData[user]` when `user==3` and `vecData.size()==3` is a serious bug. Don't do that.

Why are you always accessing `vecData[1]` instead of using the iterator?

```
  std::vector<Counter>::iterator it;

  for( it = vecData.begin(); it != vecData.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<vecData[1].age<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<vecData[1].id<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<vecData[1].pincode<<std::endl;
  }
```

You probably meant this:

```
  std::vector<Counter>::iterator it;

  for( it = vecData.begin(); it != vecData.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout<<it->age<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<it->id<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<it->pincode<<std::endl;
  }
```

Or much simpler:

```
  for (auto& c : vecData)
  {
    std::cout << c.age << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.id << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.pincode << std::endl;
  }
```

(And notice how much easier it is to read that with spaces around the `<<` operators).

> when I am trying to retrieve this data I am getting the value as 0

The reason you always get 0 printed is because you are getting the data from an un-filled vector that just contains three new `Counter` objects:

```
  Counter *count = new Counter(3);
  count->getCounterData(counterData);
```

You haven't stored any values in `count->vecData[1]` so the values you print out are just the default values created by the `Counter` constructor, which fails to initialize its members:

```
Counter::Counter()
{  
}
```

This means the member variables are just garbage. You happen to get zeros because your program has only just started so the heap happens to be full of zeros, but it's actually undefined behaviour to read those variables.

Your `Counter` class needs to initialize those members properly:

```
class Counter
{
private:
    std::vector<Counter> vecData; // vectors

public:
    Counter();
    Counter(int vecSize);
    int age = 0;
    int id = 0;
    int pincode = 0;
    void storeCounterData(Counter *counter,int user);
    void getCounterData(std::vector<Counter> &counter);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan, I understood why I was getting 0 values and tried sharing the vector between to classes using `shared_ptr` but ran in to a new error as can be seen from this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664165/segmentation-fault-on-using-shared-ptr-with-vectors?noredirect=1#comment88338534_50664165