# Segmentation fault on using shared_ptr with vectors

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I am using a shared_ptr for the first time pardon me If I have made a very silly mistake and help me in overcoming this segmentation fault.

I wish to have a private `vector` which can be read from different classes even if the object is destroyed. Hence I read about `std::shared_ptr`

The code is giving a segfault in `storeCounterData` function

Thanks in Advance for your help !!!

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "counter.hpp"
#include "getCounter.hpp"

const int max_ports = 3;

int main()
{
  Counter *counter = new Counter(3);
  counter->age = 1;
  counter->id = 12;
  counter->pincode = 123;

  std::vector<Counter*> counterData;

  std::cout<<"inside main"<<std::endl;

  counter->storeCounterData(counter,0);
  counter->storeCounterData(counter,1);
  counter->storeCounterData(counter,2);

  std::cout<<"inside main calling getCounterData"<<std::endl;
  counter->getCounterData(counterData);

  Counter countji(3);

  countji.getCounterData(counterData);

  //getCounterData class function

   getCounter *gcount = new getCounter();

   gcount->printCounterData();

  return 0;
}
```

Counter.hpp

```
#ifndef COUNTERHPP
#define COUNTERHPP
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Counter
{
private:
typedef std::shared_ptr<Counter> sharedCtr; 
std::vector<sharedCtr> vecData;
public:
Counter();
Counter(int vecSize);
int age, id, pincode;
void storeCounterData(Counter *counter,int user);
void getCounterData(std::vector<Counter*> &counter);

};

#endif
```

Counter.cpp

```
#include "counter.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

Counter::Counter()
{

}

Counter::Counter(int vecSize):vecData(vecSize)
{

}

void Counter::storeCounterData(Counter *counter,int user)
{ 
  vecData[user]->age = counter->age;
  vecData[user]->id = counter->id;
  vecData[user]->pincode = counter->pincode;

  std::cout<<"vector size inside storeCounterData = "<<vecData.size()<<std::endl;
}

void Counter::getCounterData(std::vector<Counter*> &counter)
{

  std::cout<<"vector size inside getCounterData = "<<vecData.size()<<std::endl;

for (auto& c : vecData)
  {
    std::cout << c->age << std::endl;
    std::cout << c->id << std::endl;
    std::cout << c->pincode << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output

> Bazooka~/VECTOR$ ./a.out
>
> inside main
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Where do you give `vecData` a size?

Comment: @melpomene through the constructor Counter::Counter(int vecSize):vecData(vecSize)
{

}

Comment: Oh, that's delightful. In-page search is broken in Firefox. It doesn't find that occurrence of `vecData`.

Comment: You're accessing the 4th element in a vector of size 3.

Comment: ok the segfault persists even if I pass 0 1 2 as user the problem is the way I am using and initializing the shared_ptr

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: munmap(0x7f6d5f381000, 87241)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5597a7503000
brk(0x5597a7524000)                     = 0x5597a7524000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
write(1, "inside main\n", 12inside main
)           = 12
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x18} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++

something is NULL and it has to do something with `shared_ptr`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172329/discussion-between-vinay-shukla-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Constructor of `Counter` you are creating a vector of empty `shared_ptr`s, i.e. there's no managed object of `Counter` ([see (1) here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)).

Just change the line to:

```
Counter(int vecSize) : vecData(vecSize, std::make_shared<Counter>()) {}
```

EDIT:
You are creating a vector of pointers, so I see two options here for the way you want it to work:

1. The way you did it: Instantiate the vector with 3 `shared_ptr`s, but then you need to check if the pointer was already created, whenever you access the pointer.

Maybe that's the way to go. `shared_ptr`s are pointers aswell, you should treat them like that and always check for validity.

```
Counter(int vecSize) : vecData(vecSize) {} // previous constructor

void storeCounterData(Counter* counter, int user) {
  if (!vecData[user]) {
    vecData[user] = std::make_shared<Counter>();
  }
  vecData[user]->age = counter->age;
  vecData[user]->id = counter->id;
  vecData[user]->pincode = counter->pincode;

  std::cout << "vector size inside storeCounterData = " << vecData.size()
            << std::endl;
}
void getCounterData(std::vector<Counter*>& counter) {
  std::cout << "vector size inside getCounterData = " << vecData.size()
            << std::endl;

  for (auto& c : vecData) {
    if (c) {
      std::cout << c->age << std::endl;
      std::cout << c->id << std::endl;
      std::cout << c->pincode << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use `std::vector::push_back`, so that you only have "valid" (you never can be sure of this) `shared_ptr` in the vector.

Comment: Thanks Mike that resolved the segfault but I am still getting the values in the vector as 0 for the second call of get counterData. the o/p looks like as follows.

inside main
vector size inside storeCounterData = 3
vector size inside storeCounterData = 3
vector size inside storeCounterData = 3
inside main calling getCounterData
vector size inside getCounterData = 3
1
12
123
1
12
123
1
12
123
vector size inside getCounterData = 3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
vector size inside getCounterData = 3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0